# Can't get android touch events on GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, touch

The system is not calling onTouchEvent in my application.
I've tried implementing it with onTouchEvent in the activity, the view, and the renderer. None of them get called.
So I tried dispatchTouchEvent on the activity and the view, still not getting called.
It's based off the San Angeles NDK sample, which I've compiled and that detects touch correctly.

This below is the complete java source code, everything else is native c++.

---

```
package com.example.SanAngeles;
    import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
    import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;

    public class DemoActivity extends Activity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            mGLView = new DemoGLSurfaceView(this);
            setContentView(mGLView);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            mGLView.onPause();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            mGLView.onResume();
        }

        private DemoGLSurfaceView mGLView;

        static {
            System.loadLibrary("Android");
        }
    }

    class DemoGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
        public DemoGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            mRenderer = new DemoRenderer();
            mRenderer.context = context;
            setRenderer(mRenderer);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("onTouchEvent");
            System.out.println("Motion Event" + event.getAction());
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                System.out.println("ACTION DOWN");
                final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
                System.out.println("down pcount:" + pointerCount);
                for(int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Touch x:" + event.getX(i) + "y:" + event.getY(i));
                    int id = event.getPointerId(i);
                    nativeTouchDown(id, (int)event.getX(i), (int)event.getY(i));
                }
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL) {
                final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            System.out.println("up pcount:" + pointerCount);

                for(int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
                {
                    int id = event.getPointerId(i);
                    nativeTouchUp(id);
                }
            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                final int pointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
            System.out.println("move pcount:" + pointerCount);

                for(int i = 0; i < pointerCount; i++)
                {
                    int id = event.getPointerId(i);
                    nativeTouchMove(id, (int)event.getX(i), (int)event.getY(i));
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        DemoRenderer mRenderer;

        private static native void nativePause();
    }

    class DemoRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
        Context context;
        Object am;
        public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {

            am = (Object)context.getAssets();
            System.out.println("HDROP:\n AssetManager:" + am);
            nativeInit(am, 500,500);
        }

        public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int w, int h) {
            //gl.glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
            System.out.println("Hdrop  surface changed");
            nativeResize(w, h);
        }

        public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            nativeRender();
        }

        private static native void nativeInit(Object assetManager, int w, int h);
        private static native void nativeTouchDown(int id, int x, int y);
        private static native void nativeTouchUp(int id);
        private static native void nativeTouchMove(int id, int x, int y);
        private static native void nativeResize(int w, int h);
        private static native void nativeRender();
        private static native void nativeDone();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**onTouch** works everywhere you want **(i.e if it's activity or view)** as long as you have declared the interface and put the Listener right! On the other hand **onTouchEvent** is working only inside a View

**In other words**, **onTouch() is used by users of the View** to get touch events while **onTouchEvent() is used by derived classes of the View** to get touch events

Try, replacing onTouchEvent with onTouch..

Hope this helps

Comment: I was finally able to get it to work by calling mGLView.setOnTouchListener(myListener). Thank you!

Comment: there's a official guide now: https://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/touch